# Querying spotify web-api return 404

Tags: android, spotify, asp.net-web-api

In my android application, when I try to parse the spotify web api, the page return a 404. The URL seems ok to me (http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.xml?q=album:'Meteora'+artist:'Linkin Park'), but returns 404.

Here is my code :

```
        url = new URL("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.xml?q=album:'" + albumName + "'+artist:'" +artistName +"'");

        urlc = url.openConnection();
        urlc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
        Log.v(TAG_SPOTIFY, "User-agent set: " + userAgent);
        return this.parseSpotifyURI(urlc.getInputStream());
```

Here is the error :

```
06-20 16:51:00.846: W/System.err(4962): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.xml?q=album:'Meteora'+artist:'Linkin Park'
06-20 16:51:00.846: W/System.err(4962):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
06-20 16:51:00.846: W/System.err(4962):     at com.micky.scanthings.music.ParseMusic.getSpotifyURI(ParseMusic.java:489)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, my bad. My URL wasn't encoded in UTF8, so Spotify responded with a 404.
Solution is to  parse the album name and artist that way :

```
String myURL = "album:'" + albumName + "'+artist:'" +artistName +"'";
url = new URL("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.xml?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(myURL,"UTF-8"));
```

and then do whatever we want with this URL.